# Custom Field bool type some time insert false in ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have add few custom field in **ApplicationUser** Class and adding in **Aspnetusers**.
some time one field "**IsActive**" it's insert properly as hardcoded **true** by default but for few user insert **false**.

Class is

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public virtual string UsedReferralCode { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserType { get; set; }

    public virtual bool? IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int UniqueId { get; set; }

    public virtual string FaceBookId { get; set; }

    public virtual string AppleId { get; set; }

}
```

Register user Code

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    PhoneNumber = model.Mobile,
                    CountryCode = model.CountryCode,
                    UsedReferralCode = model.ReferralCode,
                    RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
                    UserType = "Register",
                    IsActive = true



                };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I didn't understand why its insert false for few users.
suggest some idea.

Thanks

Comment: Do you update your user in some place?For example,using `await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);`

Comment: Yes and using everywhere like this  var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Userid).ConfigureAwait(false); like this so there is no chances to set false coz all parameters coming from database as true.